# Rails default error page doesn't show on development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, raise

I built an error handler that, when there's an error in any controller method in production, reroutes the user to an error page and sends me, the developer, a notification email. This works, but I want the normal error screen to appear when I'm in development. I assumed the code to produce this was just `raise e`, but instead in development I'm now getting the default *production* error page (the one that says "We're sorry, but something went wrong".), instead of the detailed error message and trace that used to appear.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from StandardError, with: :handle_error

  #error handler
  def handle_error(e)
    if Rails.env.production?
      #code to send email and redirect to error page
    else
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

I also tried the following:

```
raise
raise StandardError.new e
raise e, e.message
raise e.message
```

and if I run any of those in a `binding.pry` console, they produce the error message I'm looking for, but the error page still just says "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

**Anyone know how I can just show the default development error page?**

---

### **UPDATE**

This is insane...so the code to display an error normally should definitely work, but something somewhere is preventing that. If I change `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` on production, the errors show up on production, but then even if I copy and paste my config/environments/production.rb file into my config/environments/development.rb, the errors still don't show on development. If I enter a pry console, `request.local?` returns "0", signifying true, and `Rails.env` returns "development". I have no idea what is going on.

### **UPDATE 2**

Apparently I'm not supposed to be rescuing exceptions on development, but even if I delete every bit of custom error handling code so my Application Controller is just empty, my errors still don't show on development. Further, I have a different app with the same exact error handling code, and for that the errors do show.

Comment: I've just pasted your code on a random app here and it worked as expected! 

Maybe something else on your code that is the problem? Some  `application.rb` or `development.rb` configuration? When on pry, `Rails.env` return the correct environment? Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: @LeonardoPrado Huh, that's weird, but you're right! I removed all my custom error handling code and the error page still has no details. I'm using Rails 6.0.0.rc1 and Rails.env does return "development"...

Comment: @JoeMorano Did you figure this out? I am stuck in the exact same situation. I am running on development mode and `consider_all_requests_local` is set to true, but I still can't get the full errors in the browser. Even inside a view `Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local` returns true and `request.local?` returns true.

Comment: After a few hours, I realized that I jumped from 5.2 to 6.1, without first upgrading to 6.0. This seemed to have caused the issue. I rolled back, upgraded to 6.0 and then to 6.1 and the issue was resolved. Probably some new app defaults were missing and caused this.

Answer (score 4):

Search your code for `consider_all_requests_local`, it's this configuration that show the full error log.

It must be set as `true` on your `development.rb` config file. It's either missing from your configs, or other config is overwriting it

Comment: That's what I thought too. I just ran a search for `consider_all_requests_local` on my entire codebase, and the only three instances are development.rb, where it's set to `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`, production.rb, where it's set to false, and test.rb, where it's set to true. When in a pry console, `request.local?` returns "0", which means true, and `Rails.env` returns "development".

Comment: Again,it should have worked… Is spring working? Have you restarted it?

Comment: Another test you can do: create a method `def local_request?; true; end` on your controller, it should force it to show the dev errors page, see if it works

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, but even weirder, I changed `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` on production, and the full errors did show up there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not "insane", this is completely expected behavior. You cannot `raise` from within a `rescue_from` handler. That would cause an infinite loop.

You also **cannot `rescue_from StandardError`** as stated specifically in the documentation:

> Using rescue_from with Exception or StandardError would cause serious side-effects as it prevents Rails from handling exceptions properly. As such, it is not recommended to do so unless there is a strong reason.

Instead of conditionally handling the exception inside your `rescue_from`handler, you should conditionally bind the handler, and pick a more specific exception class to handle.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from StandardError, with: :handle_error if Rails.env.production?

  #error handler
  def handle_error(e)
    #code to send email and redirect to error page
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a weird coincidence that my code isn't supposed to work anyway, because my app doesn't give error messages on development even when I delete all the rescue_from stuff. Further, I have another app that has exactly the code given in this question (raising in a rescue_from), and that app shows errors in development like normal.

Answer (score 0):

create ErrorsController like below

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
   skip_before_action :login

   def not_found
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render status: 404 }
       format.json { render json: { error: "Not found" }, status: 404 }
     end
   end
end
```